# reading part of svg file in qt

Tags: qt

I need to read a part of a .svg file.
   There are many graphs in the .svg file related to values.
   Is there any way that each graph can be represented as a tab in Qt?
Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

[`QSvgRenderer`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsvgrenderer.html) allows you to render specific elements from the SVG according to their `id` inside a widget. Managing tabs is a whole different thing and you'll need to do it using a `QTabWidget`

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure that the id they're talking about here is the XML id of the item in the SVG xml. for instance:

```
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0"> ... </symbol>
```

if your SVG doesn't have ids, you'll have to modify it to include them.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but how will I come to know the id of the element. The id was not assigned when the file was made?
I tried using QGraphicsSvgItem, but the returned string is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I included the id's while creating the .svg file and I get the co-ordinates for a particular graph that I need, using QGraphicsSvgItem, but is there any way to convert the image into a widget so that it can be included into QTabWidget?

Comment: You can use QSvgWidget to be parented by a QWidget and be placed in any tab you want. but how did you managed to create ids while creating svgs?